# Bootstrap error: Working on Mobile/ Laptop but not desktop

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I am new to front end development and modiying an exisiting form on a landing page (adding an extra column). When I add this column, it renders fine on all devices (except a desktop).

I would appreciate pointers on possible causes and how to fix this.

Here is a copy of my code below:

```
    <div class="fields">
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 lbl"><label>First Name*</label></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 fld"><input type="text" maxlength="40" name="fname" id="fname" required/></div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 lbl"><label>Last Name*</label></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 fld"><input type="text" maxlength="40" name="lname" id="lname" required/></div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 lbl" style="padding-right:0px"><label>Email Address*</label></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 fld"><input type="email" name="email" id="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" required /></div>
                    </div>    
                    <div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 lbl"><label>Gender*</label></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 fld">
                            <label style="width: 100px;"><input class="gender" type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="Female"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;Female</label>
                            <label><input class="gender" type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="Male"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;Male</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 lbl"><label>Date of Birth*</label></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 fld" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
                            <select id="daydropdown" style="width: 64px" name="date" id="date" required><option value="" disabled selected>DD</option></select>
                            <select id="monthdropdown" style="width: 64px" name="month" id="month" required><option value="" disabled selected>MM</option></select> 
                            <select id="yeardropdown" style="width: 74px" name="year" id="year" required><option value="" disabled selected>YYYY</option></select> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 lbl"><label>Country*</label></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 fld"><select id="countrydropdown" style="width: 100%;" name="country" id="country" required><option value="">--Please Select--
                        </option>
                        </select></div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 lbl"><label>Postcode*</label></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 fld"><input type="text" maxlength="20" name="postcode" id="postcode" required/></div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 lbl">
                        <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td><span><input type="checkbox" id="signupcheckbox"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></td>
                            <td><span>I would like to sign up to emails</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: We can not guess what you did

Comment: Will update now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have problem in your mark-up. Try something like this--

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="fields container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                        <div class=" lbl"><label>First Name*</label></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 fld"><input type="text" maxlength="40" name="fname" id="fname" required/></div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class=" lbl"><label>Last Name*</label></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 fld"><input type="text" maxlength="40" name="lname" id="lname" required/></div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class=" lbl" style="padding-right:0px"><label>Email Address*</label></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 fld"><input type="email" name="email" id="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" required /></div>
                    </div>    
                    <div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class=" lbl"><label>Gender*</label></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 fld">
                            <label style="width: 100px;"><input class="gender" type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="Female"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;Female</label>
                            <label><input class="gender" type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="Male"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;Male</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class=" lbl"><label>Date of Birth*</label></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 fld" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
                            <select id="daydropdown" style="width: 64px" name="date" id="date" required><option value="" disabled selected>DD</option></select>
                            <select id="monthdropdown" style="width: 64px" name="month" id="month" required><option value="" disabled selected>MM</option></select> 
                            <select id="yeardropdown" style="width: 74px" name="year" id="year" required><option value="" disabled selected>YYYY</option></select> 
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 lbl"><label>Country*</label></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 fld"><select id="countrydropdown" style="width: 100%;" name="country" id="country" required><option value="">--Please Select--
                        </option>
                        </select></div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="lbl"><label>Postcode*</label></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 fld"><input type="text" maxlength="20" name="postcode" id="postcode" required/></div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 lbl">
                        <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td><span><input type="checkbox" id="signupcheckbox"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></td>
                            <td><span>I would like to sign up to emails</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

share the code  or use

in bootstrap use

```
class="col-lg-14 col-md-14 col-sm-5 col-xs-12"
```

for desktop use lg and md

Comment: where from you get col-lg-14 ? we have only 12 available in bootstrap

Comment: that is for reference i put..,i created lg-14 in my project..,you can change it into lg-12, or go to css and create...

Comment: Great to hear about it. but for layman it is confusing and is against bootstrap standards :)